# Reading memory through a Python script invoked by JUCE

Tags: python, astropy, fits, juce

I wrote a Python script which has the task to download a FITS file, in order to read the data of a star, through the exploitation of the library `astropy`. Unfortunately, I can't write anything to the disk, because the returned `pValue` is always NULL when my program try to access the memory on the disk.

This is the C++ code written with the JUCE Framework:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <JuceHeader.h>
#include <Python.h>

void myFunction()
{

    Py_Initialize();

    PyRun_SimpleString("import pandas as pd");
    PyRun_SimpleString("from datetime import date");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import time");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import requests");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import json");
    PyRun_SimpleString("from astroquery.mast import Observations");
    PyRun_SimpleString("from astropy.coordinates import EarthLocation, AltAz, SkyCoord");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import astropy.units as u");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import os");
    PyRun_SimpleString("from astropy.io import fits");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import importTry");

    PyObject* pyName = PyUnicode_FromString("hello");
    PyObject* pyModule = PyImport_Import(pyName);

    if (pyModule != NULL)
    {
        PyObject* pyDict = PyModule_GetDict(pyModule);

        PyObject* pyClass = PyDict_GetItemString(pyDict, "Hello");

        if (PyCallable_Check(pyClass)) {
            PyObject* pyInstance = PyObject_CallObject(pyClass, NULL);

            PyObject* pValue = PyObject_CallMethod(pyInstance, "print_hello", NULL);

            if (pValue == NULL)
            {
                DBG("ERROR");
            }
            else
            {
                auto result = _PyUnicode_AsString(pValue);
                DBG(result);
            }
        }
    }

    Py_Finalize();
}
```

This is the Python script:

```
from datetime import date 
import time
from typing import final
import requests
from astroquery.mast import Observations
from astropy.coordinates import EarthLocation, AltAz, SkyCoord
import astropy.units as u
from astropy.io import fits
import pandas as pd
import os
import json
import importTry

class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def print_hello(self):

        def getSkyCoord(ra, dec):
            skyCoord = SkyCoord(ra=ra * u.deg, dec=dec * u.deg, representation_type='spherical')
            return skyCoord

        def getAltAz(skyCoord, observerTime, location):
            altAz = skyCoord.transform_to(AltAz(obstime=observerTime, location=location))
            return altAz

        def getAltAngle(altAz):
            alt = (altAz.alt * u.deg).value
            return alt

        def getAzAngle(altAz):
            az = (altAz.az * u.deg).value
            return az

        def getConstellation(name_flamsteed_full):
            name_split = str(name_flamsteed_full).split('-')
            constellation = name_split[1]
            return constellation
        db = importTry.data
        bright_stars = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(db, orient='index')

        # Getting the current date
        today = date.today()
        theTime = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        observerTime = str(today) + " " + str(theTime)
    
        # Getting the current location. It is necessary to be connected to
        # the internet
        location = requests.get('http://ipinfo.io/json').json()
        location = EarthLocation.of_address(location['city'] + ", " + location['region'])
    
        bright_stars['SkyCoord'] = bright_stars.apply(lambda row : getSkyCoord(row['ra'], row['dec']), axis=1)
        bright_stars['AltAz'] = bright_stars.apply(lambda row: getAltAz(row['SkyCoord'], observerTime, location), axis=1)
        bright_stars['Altitude'] = bright_stars.apply(lambda row: getAltAngle(row['AltAz']), axis=1)
        bright_stars['Azimuth'] = bright_stars.apply(lambda row: getAzAngle(row['AltAz']), axis=1)

        bright_stars = bright_stars.drop(['SkyCoord', 'AltAz'], axis=1)
        bright_stars['Constellation'] = bright_stars.apply(lambda row: getConstellation(row['name_flamsteed_full']), axis=1)
    
        bright_stars = bright_stars[bright_stars['Constellation'] != '']
        bright_stars = bright_stars.reset_index(drop=True)
    
        visible_stars = bright_stars[bright_stars['Altitude'] >= 0]
        not_visible_stars = bright_stars[bright_stars['Altitude'] < 0]
    
        camelopardalis = visible_stars[visible_stars["name_flamsteed_full"].str.contains("Cam", na=False)]
        a_star = camelopardalis.sample()
        skyCoord = SkyCoord(ra=float(a_star['ra']) * u.deg, dec=float(a_star['dec']) * u.deg, representation_type='spherical')
        radius = 0.5 * u.arcminute
    
        obs_object = Observations.query_object(skyCoord.to_string(), radius=radius)
        timeseries_df = obs_object[obs_object['dataproduct_type'] == 'timeseries']
        filename = timeseries_df[0]['dataURL'].split('/')[2]
    
        url_start = 'https://mast.stsci.edu/api/v0.1/Download/file?uri=mast:TESS/product/'
        url_complete = url_start + filename
        data = fits.open(name=url_complete, mode='denywrite', cache=False
    
        return url_complete
```

When I get to the line `data = fits.open(name=url_complete, mode='denywrite', cache=False)`, I get an error. I suspect that the problem resides in the fact that I can't perform any I/O operations when I launch a Python script from JUCE. Any suggestion on how to manage this situation?

Comment: I don't know what JUCE is. But if it somehow is blocking *any* I/O then you certainly won't be able to download a file either.

Comment: Also what is the error?

Comment: @Iguananaut JUCE is a framework for developing audio applications, both standalone and VST. However, after several attempts I found out a "workaround" for writing in memory, thus bypassing the I/O block

Comment: @Iguananaut Simply, the error is: the `pyValue` returned is always NULL, even if the Python script runs correctly

Comment: However: I will post the solution that I found out ASAP